# XML in Android Studio: Wrapcontent in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I need to have items arranged vertically in this order: TextView, LinearLayout (under the textview), then BottomNavigationView. But the result is this:

[image]

I have this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Home"
            />

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:id="@+id/fragmentholder"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"

            app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this to the `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/message"
    android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentholder"
    android:orientation="vertical">
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Home"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/message"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"

        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This comes in the order "TextView, LinearLayout (under the textview)" specified in the question. 
The android:gravity="centre" feature is used to 'Place the object in the center of its container in both the vertical and horizontal axis, not changing its size.' for the TextView.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you add some more context to your answer, describing why it works to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

ou can make something like this: with property `layout_below`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Home"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/message"
            android:id="@+id/fragmentholder"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```